# FXCOP analysis with SONARQube fails the build and SONAR analysis never completes and hence analysis results never reached SONAR server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, fxcopcmd

FXCOP analysis with SONARQube fails the build and SONAR analysis never completes and hence analysis results never reached SONAR server.

So How to make the FXCOP analysis result publish at the SONAR server.

I am using SONAR 5.6 and sonar scanner for msbuild 2.2

Comment: You should provide at least the relevant Sonar Log fragment (in debug or trace mode).

Comment: The issue is When I add FXCOP rules plugin to SONAR and use that rules as default rules in CI then on building solution with MSBUILD CLI commands, RunCodeAnalysis triggers and Code analysis Errors get displayed.after than when I execute the following command "C:\\Jenkins\\tools\\sonar-scanner-msbuild-2.2.0.24\\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end throws error as "
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube ana
lysis."